# Publish with Subitem functionality

Tags: publishing, workflow

I have a root item and subitems. When i publish the Item with Subitem option checked, the root item is published but the below items if in draft state are not published.
For example:

In the below image the custom submit button is published with subitem but the Submit action folder is still in draft state and not published:

[image]

Is this expected behaviour? How the publish with subitem works? what can be the fix to publish all the subitem at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behaviour. You need to submit the workflow in the final state before publishing or you can remove the workflow from the item if you don't need it. but it is recommended to use proper workflow and also if you will publish the item only the latest version will publish.